# How to POST a request in a hybrid application using phone gap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I having a post request with parmeters in hidden field which needs to be redirected to a different site(payment site) in button click which is working correctly in my browser but not working correctly in android device.The site responds with
ExtraFields_f14 parameter is invalid though i have set the value

```
<form method="post" name="redirectForm" id="redirectForm" action="https://g2testi.edirhamg2.ae/PayOnePCB/PaymentPayServlet">
     <input type="hidden" id="Amount" name="Amount" value="100" /> 
     <input type="hidden" id="Currency" name="Currency" value="784" /> 
     <input type="hidden" id="ExtraFields_f14" name="ExtraFields_f14" value="http://..." /> 
</form>
```

i have tried using window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes') but no luck
I have referenced this phone gap library in my html page

my script

```
<script src="../Scripts/phonegap-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  function OnSuccess(response) {
    $("form#redirectForm").submit();
  }
```

how can i get this site opened in my android device Anyone who knows please give your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Create a call like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url-to-your-php-or=something.php",
  data: {
         amount: $('#Amount').val(),
         currency: $('#Currency').val(),
         ExtraFields_f14: $('#ExtraFields_f14').val()
      }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.The ExtraFields_f14 paramater is redirect url to my application.

Comment: have you set `url` to `https://g2testi.edirhamg2.ae/PayOnePCB/PaymentPayServlet` and checked what's send with the developers tool? Could you provide a printscreen or something of what is send?

Comment: i am getting this issue only in my android device when i install and go through the application

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = your_service_URL; 
var str = $('#redirectForm').serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: str,      
  success: function(response){

  }
}).done(function() {

})
```